# How to remove additional/outer square brackets for lists which are formed by 'zip' function

Tags: python-3.x, list, argv

I am trying to find standard deviation for different lists and have written code as below

**Code 1:**

```
from statistics import stdev
def test_var_args(a,b,c):
    std = []
    myZip=zip(argv)
    list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list(myZip)]
    print(list_of_lists)
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
        std.append(stdev(list_of_lists[i]))
    return std
```

**Input**:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[2,4,1,6]
c=[1,7,2,4]
test_var_args(a,b,c)
```

With the above input the code gave me expected results.

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 7], [3, 1, 2], [4, 6, 4]]
[0.5773502691896257, 2.516611478423583, 1.0, 1.1547005383792515]
```

As my requirement is to pass more lists and find standard deviation, i have used *argv and modified my code as below-

**Modified code:**

```
def test_var_args(*argv):
    print("the positional arguments are:", argv)
    std = []
    myZip=zip(argv)
    list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list(myZip)]
    print(list_of_lists)
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
        std.append(stdev(list_of_lists[i]))       
    return std
```

**Output:**

```
the positional arguments are: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1, 6], [1, 7, 2, 4])
[[[1, 2, 3, 4]], [[2, 4, 1, 6]], [[1, 7, 2, 4]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-106-3d2d4dcb9408>", line 18, in <module>
    test_var_args(a,b,c)

  File "<ipython-input-106-3d2d4dcb9408>", line 10, in test_var_args
    std.append(stdev(list_of_lists[i]))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\statistics.py", line 650, in stdev
    var = variance(data, xbar)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\statistics.py", line 588, in variance
    raise StatisticsError('variance requires at least two data points')

StatisticsError: variance requires at least two data points
```

How can i remove the extra square brackets from the modified code output, so that 'StatisticsError' will not occur

Comment: `list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list(myZip)]` is what is creating the outer brackets (brackets are square, braces are curly, just FYI). [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator of tuples.

Comment: @pstatix : With the tuple to list conversion , always there is 'StatisticsError: variance requires at least two data points' displayed.

Comment: Thought this post got deleted. Huh. Change `myZip=zip(argv)` to `myZip=zip(*argv)`.

Comment: @pstatix : Here is the result with myZip=zip(*argv)                                         >>test_var_args(a,b,c)
>>the positional arguments are: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1, 6], [1, 7, 2, 4])
>> []                                                                                                                                      a blank list is being returned